# Trouble logging in from Windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-8, login

I have trouble logging into a storage server from my Windows 8 PC. I was previously able to log in from a Windows Vista PC, and I am even able to log in from a Windows XP VM on the same Windows 8 PC. However, when I try to log in directly from the Windows 8 PC, it kept prompting me for the password. I noticed that it is trying to log in using the domain that is my PC name. Could this be the problem?

ETA: A bit more details on what I see.

I have tried accessing it using the IP address, and I can access those folders within the server that do not require logins. When I tried to access a folder that does require login, I first tried to simply enter my username and password. I then get another prompt:

```
Enter your credentials to connect to: <ip address>
<PCName>\<username>
[Password prompt]
```

I just keep getting the error

```
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that your computer is connect  to the network that uses a domain to manage network computers so please try to connect the storage server using the ip address instead of hostname.

Comment: I have tried using the ip address, but I still get the same problem. I have included a bit more details in my original post above.